# Raven DB: What's wrong with this multimap/reduce index?

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb

My Sum and Max calls on last used and usage count are wrong. They are always the value that is stored in the second maps value which is currently set to 0. I can make it -100 and that is what the reduce result will be. I noticed someone saying that you should make it an array but I don't understand how that helps. I have a linq expression over objects using the map/reduce that works properly assuming that the two maps are unioned together.

Here's the data => https://gist.github.com/940ccca1b0f8917e9eaf

I want to support a query like

```
        var stats = Session.Query<MultiMapApiKeyStats.ApiKeyStats, MultiMapApiKeyStats>()
            .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())
            .Where(x => x.AccountId == Account.Id)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

and build a table like
[image: table]

```
 public MultiMapApiKeyStats()
        {
            AddMap<KeyUsageBase>(uses => from use in uses
                                         select new
                                         {
                                             AccountId = use.AccountId,
                                             ApiKeyId = use.ApiKeyId,
                                             Key = (string)null,
                                             UsageCount = 1,
                                             LastUsed = use.LastUsedTicks,
                                             Pattern = (string)null,
                                             Status = ApiKey.KeyStatus.None,
                                             Type = ApiKey.ApplicationType.None
                                         });
            AddMap<ApiKey>(keys => from key in keys
                                   select new
                                          {
                                              AccountId = key.AccountId,
                                              ApiKeyId = key.Id,
                                              Key = key.Key,
                                              UsageCount = 0,
                                              LastUsed = 0,
                                              Pattern = key.Pattern,
                                              Status = key.ApiKeyStatus,
                                              Type = key.Type
                                          });


            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by result.ApiKeyId
                                    into g
                                    select new
                                           {
                                           AccountId = g.Select(x => x.AccountId).FirstOrDefault(),
                                           ApiKeyId = g.Key,
                                           Key = g.Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                                           UsageCount = g.Sum(x => x.UsageCount),
                                           LastUsed = g.Max(x => x.LastUsed),
                                           Pattern = g.Select(x => x.Pattern).FirstOrDefault(),
                                           Status = g.Select(x => x.Status).FirstOrDefault(),
                                           Type = g.Select(x => x.Type).FirstOrDefault()
                                           };
```

Comment: One things that seems off is that the group by should be: group result by new { result.AccountId, result.ApiKeyId }. Also, why is, for example, Pattern in the result set at all? Or Status and Type?

Comment: those are place holders at the moment. what do i gain by grouping by both?

Comment: That seems like the logical thing, though I don't know you data model. I think the actual cause is that ApiKey.ApplicationType.None is a static member available in your code, however when RavenDB goes to index, it doesn't reference your code base and doesn't know how to handle it. You can only reference BCL types in the map and reduce declarations.

Comment: i updated the reduce to not use those place holders. the index works in the RDBMS but the lastused and usage count are 0. if i groupby new accountid and apikeyid it doesn't show any records.

Comment: Are there any index errors showing up in the studio? Did you remove references to your classes from map/reduce declarations? Also, try using FirstOrDefault instead of First.

Comment: there are some old errors about sequence contains no matching elements but the terms and query work now.

Comment: wow, using firstordefault fixed the problem...

Comment: post an answer and i'll mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexing error `sequence contains no matching elements` is a result of invoking `First` on an empty collection which is why you should use `FirstOrDefault`. Also, referencing your own classes in map and reduce declarations will cause errors because RavenDB can't resolve those types at indexing time.

Comment: so why does the sequence contain no elements? i'm mapping all my documents to something or was the pattern the only culprit?

Comment: It could have something to do with the way RavenDB performs the reduce which assumes that the collection could be empty.